# Janusgraph : Cassandra thrift timeout exception

Tags: java, graph, cassandra, janusgraph

I am using Janusgraph in embedded format with backend as cassandrathrift. Here are my properties for janusgraph and cassandra:

```
storage.backend=cassandrathrift
storage.cassandra.keyspace=t_graph
storage.cassandra.frame-size-mb=128
storage.hostname=10.XX.XX.XX,20.XX.XX.XX,30.XX.XX.XX
```

And i have a query which finds out the followers count of a particular vertex. Here is the code for that:

```
public class FollowCountNormal {

    private static JanusGraph graph;
    private static GraphTraversalSource traversalSource;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        create();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public static JanusGraph create() {

        graph = JanusGraphFactory.open("/resources/jp.properties");
        traversalSource = graph.traversal();
        getAllEdges();
        return graph;
    }

    static long getAllEdges(){

        try{
            GraphTraversal<Vertex, Vertex> allV = traversalSource.V();
            GraphTraversal<Vertex, Vertex> gt = allV.has("vid", "supernode");
            GraphTraversal<Vertex, Long> c = gt.inE()           
                    .count();
            long l = c.next();
            System.out.println("All edges = "+l);
            graph.tx().commit();
            return l;
        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error while fetching the edges for : ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return -1;
    }
}
```

This code works fine if the vertex have a limited number of incoming Edges (i.e. works fine is follower count is less than 100000). But if the followers count is in millions, i got the following exception:

> Caused by: org.janusgraph.diskstorage.PermanentBackendException:
>   Permanent failure in storage backend  at
>   org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cassandra.thrift.CassandraThriftKeyColumnValueStore.convertException(CassandraThriftKeyColumnValueStore.java:263)
>     at
>   org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cassandra.thrift.CassandraThriftKeyColumnValueStore.getNamesSlice(CassandraThriftKeyColumnValueStore.java:162)
>     at
>   org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cassandra.thrift.CassandraThriftKeyColumnValueStore.getNamesSlice(CassandraThriftKeyColumnValueStore.java:105)
>     at
>   org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cassandra.thrift.CassandraThriftKeyColumnValueStore.getSlice(CassandraThriftKeyColumnValueStore.java:94)
>     at
>   org.janusgraph.diskstorage.keycolumnvalue.KCVSProxy.getSlice(KCVSProxy.java:77)
>     at
>   org.janusgraph.diskstorage.keycolumnvalue.cache.ExpirationKCVSCache$2.call(ExpirationKCVSCache.java:100)
>     at
>   org.janusgraph.diskstorage.keycolumnvalue.cache.ExpirationKCVSCache$2.call(ExpirationKCVSCache.java:96)
>     at
>   com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache$1.load(LocalCache.java:4742)
>     at
>   com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3527)
>     at
>   com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2319)
>     ... 50 common frames omitted Caused by:
>   org.apache.cassandra.thrift.TimedOutException: null   at
>   org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$multiget_slice_result$multiget_slice_resultStandardScheme.read(Cassandra.java:14696)    at
>   org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$multiget_slice_result$multiget_slice_resultStandardScheme.read(Cassandra.java:14633)    at
>   org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$multiget_slice_result.read(Cassandra.java:14559)
>     at
>   org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:78)
>     at
>   org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.recv_multiget_slice(Cassandra.java:741)
>     at
>   org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.multiget_slice(Cassandra.java:725)
>     at
>   org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cassandra.thrift.CassandraThriftKeyColumnValueStore.getNamesSlice(CassandraThriftKeyColumnValueStore.java:143)
>     ... 58 common frames omitted

I looked for many posts online like this:

[link1](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/issues/1467)

but no solution worked for me. Any suggestion on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the storage backend to cql and other properties relevant to cql solved the issue for me.
Here are the properties which i used:

```
storage.backend=cql
storage.cql.keyspace=t_graph
storage.cql.read-consistency-level=ONE
```